# Merge Rx Observables according to date

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

I want to populate a listview with headers (Date) and content below (plannings in this date).
I have 2 Lists, one for headers, one for content, and I want to have one as output.

This is the current implementation which seems very inefficient.

Is there a way to do it as one single Observable that merges the two lists and outputs one? It should output header-date first, than **if** plannings are available on this day the plannings, and then the next header.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            int currentHeaderPosition = listItems.size();
            LocalDate currentDate = startDate.plusDays(i);
            listItems.add(currentDate);
            Observable.fromIterable(data.shiftPlannings)
                    .filter(planning -> planning.getStartTime().compareTo(currentDate) == 0)
                    .subscribe(planning -> {
                        listItems.add(planning);});

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

From your code, it's seems you acting on in-memory data, so Rx is not the right tool for that, Rx is for collections/events over time.

You can easily do it, have list/array of lists per day of week, iterate over the plannings objects and add each planning to the matched list.